# What does (for the last day) mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

> He has locked himself in his room for the last day .

does this mean that he's been in his room all day long ?

i could understand it if someone said they have been doing something for the last two days / the last week / the last 10 years , but i have never heard (for the last day) before. is it because it's not that commonly used ?

thanks in advance

Comment: The question needs some context, please.

Comment: of course .the man's father passed away a month before ,and the man has never been the same since , he's been drinking and so depressed ,on that day he locks himself in his room , so his wife calls the police to report that because she's concerned about him taking his own life .

Comment: It's just like you suppose. For the last day, for the last two days... In this case, imagine the speaker putting emphasis on "day". He has locked himself in his room for the last ***day***.